# How to post in Facebook with @mention ability using stream.publish?

Tags: facebook

I would like to include inline links friends within the message of a stream.publish call.  Here is example pyFacebook code:

Code:

```
facebook.request_extended_permission("publish_stream")
facebook.stream.publish("@John Doe is cool")
```

Is there a way to include markup in the message to do this?

src: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=339920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook had included a way to do this notifications, about 2 years ago but unfortunately, the functionality hasn't made it's way into the stream publishing methods.  So, for right now, it's not possible to tag a user's friends in a post that you are composing via your application.  ::sad trombone:: heh

Comment: it was possible for a while. i do not know if it is still possible. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12947